# Counting "High-Only" hands in Omaha 8 or better

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to enumerate the possible 5-card (of standard 52 deck) combinations that exclude the possibility of a low-hand to qualify in Omaha poker 8 or better.

Brief rules re low hand qualification: the board (flop, turn, river - 5 cards in total) must contain at least three unpaired low cards (Ace, 2,3 ..., 8) in order low to qualify.

Aces are low cards, so there are total of 32 low and 20 high cards in the deck.

There are following low-excluding combinations by the river card. (LL) would mean a pair of the low cards, (LLL) - trips, (LLLL) - 4 of a kind.

Enumeration attempt:

1. HHHHH - C(20,5)
2. HHHHL - C(20,4)*C(32,1)
3. HHHLL - C(20,3)*C(8,2)*4*4
   Choose 2 ranks of the 8 low raanks, times suits each of the low cards can take.
4. HHL(LL) - C(20,2)*C(8,1)*4*C(7,1)*C(4,2)
5. HH(LLL) - C(20,2)*C(8,1)*C(4,3)
6. HL(LLL) - C(20,1)*C(8,1)*4*C(7,1)*C(4,3)
7. H(LL)(LL) - C20,1*C(8,2)*C(4,2)*C(4,2)
8. H(LLLL) - C(20,1)*(8,1)
9. L(LLLL) - C(8,1)*4*C(7,1)
10. (LLL)(LL) - C(8,1)*C(4,3)*C(7,1)*C(4,2)

I would appreciate if somebody could verify if my thoughts are right, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all looks good – there's just one mistake as far as I can see: You should also be excluding HHH(LL), of which there are $\binom{20}3\binom81\binom42$, or preferably you could count HHHLL and HHH(LL) together as $\binom{20}3\binom{32}2$.

The entire endeavour could be simplified by counting the complement instead:

HHLLL: $\binom{20}2\binom834^3$

HLLLL: $\binom{20}1\binom844^4$

LLLLL: $\binom{20}0\binom854^5$

(LL)LLL: $\binom81\binom42\binom734^3$

Adding up the two counts to $\binom{52}5$ gives you a good check (I didn't do it).

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are right of course, I missed the HHH(LL), and I took your advise and enumerated the low-qualifying hands as well, adding: HLL(LL), LL(LLL), L(LL)(LL). It all adds up to C(52,5) in total, and I am very happy )). Appreciate your guidance.

Comment: @SKYTTEN: I see, I'd misunderstood the rules. I'd taken the "unpaired" to mean "unpaired within the entire hand", but of course it only means "unpaired within those three", since they'll be combined with two cards from the board, not with the two other hand cards. (Of course then I should have noted that these weren't included in your list of excluded hands.)